# Why does MariaDB keep quitting on me?

Tags: mariadb

I recently setup a new server for a basic PHP/MySQL web application. I've used MySQL for this app in the past. I've been hearing a lot about MariaDB as a drop-in replacement for MySQL lately, so I figured I'd give it a shot.

I've been using it for about a month now and it works great, except for when the database randomly crashes, which has happened twice so far. The first time the server was up for about 20 days before the DB crashed, the second time it only lasted a week.

If I try to restart the database after it has crashed, I get the following output:

```
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.11-MariaDB-1~trusty) starting as process 32229 ...
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/myapp-production.lower-test
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'myisam_recover' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'myisam-recover-options' instead.
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] Aborting
```

This information is logged in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`.

The only way I'm able to get the MariaDB server working again is to reboot the whole VPS. I can see memory use drop from about 300 MB to 200 MB by checking New Relic.

Is this a memory problem? It's a DigitalOcean VPS with 512 MB of RAM. New Relic shows 490 MB of available RAM and total memory usage hasn't exceeded 310 MB in the past month. The `mysqld` process consumes an average of 102 MB. The whole database only holds 12 MB of total data.

Other than the output that I get when attempting to reboot the database, I'm not seeing anything logged regarding this problem.

- How can I determine what is causing MariaDB to crash?
- How can I reboot the database without rebooting the whole VPS?

Answer (score 0):

This is the important part:

> 2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be
>   opened in read-write mode
>   2016-03-01 12:38:33 139733177079744 [ERROR]
>   InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

Did you install MariaDB as root?

Did you put the directory in a writable tree on a writable filesystem?

512MB is *tiny*, but probably not relevant to the startup failure.